# Posts are not showing up on particular category

Tags: posts, categories, get-posts

On my website, post are not showing up when I navigate to

```
http://www.domain.com/category/category-name/
```

but on wordpress dashboard, I am able to see the actual number of post under that category. It is not getting displayed on website only.

Also, when I am logged in to the wordpress dashboard and visit that category page,

```
http://www.domain.com/category/category-name/
```

I am not seeing the wp admin bar which used to show on top. but it is showing up on other pages.

Comment: Rather impossible to diagnose with example/placeholder URLs.

Comment: http://goo.gl/rzXotK here is my URL

Comment: You clearly have posts in the `election2014` category, e.g. [here](http://www.newslaundry.com/2014/04/07/voting-guide-map/). Does this problem persist if you switch to a core-bundled Theme (such as Twenty Twelve), and with all Plugins disabled? If not, please narrow down the cause to your Theme, or to a specific Plugin.

Comment: I cannot check it on the live site as you are saying. Is there any other way to find the rootcause?

Comment: It's your site; only you can do that level of debugging.

Comment: Are you sure there are posts attached to that category? It looks like a parent category so make sure that your posts are attributed to it and not just one of the child categories. All your other categories and sub/child categories look as though they are displaying fine.